# open FileSelect dialog programmatically

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to have a FileSelect dialogue box pop open without user interaction, but it doesn't work and I don't understand why.

In this example, I am trying to have it opened by the window.onload function, but it doesn't do anything. The console output shows that the "simulateclick()" function is executed, but I don't see the dialogue box.

When I use the 'test' button instead, it works fine.

Also calling "document.getElementById('files').click()" from the console has no effect whatsoever.

Can anybody explain?

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="file" id="files" name="files[]" multiple>
<input type="button" id="test" value="test">
<script>
function simulateclick(){
    console.log("before");
    var elem = document.getElementById('files');
    console.log(elem);
    elem.click();
    console.log("after");
};
window.onload = simulateclick;
document.getElementById('test').onclick = simulateclick;
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't think this is possible. Browsers require a user action to start a file select dialogue last I checked. But maybe there is a new way to do this i'm not aware of.